# I cant run scapy shell, but it does work as module in python script

Tags: python, scapy

I had problems with python because I had more than one version on my computer.
so I deleted them all.. and when I installed new python and reinstalled the scapy module, it worked as a module.. but when I am trying to run scapy shhel from the cmd I get this error:

```
file "C:\Users\משתמש\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\scapy-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xee' in file C:\Users\מש**תמש\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\scapy-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: can you add what you typed to invoke the scapy shell?

Comment: I just typed scapy at the cmd... I worked before, the problem started  after I reinstalled python